# Display mp3 songs in a listview from sd card

Tags: android-listview

i want to display **mp3 songs** from sd card in listview. I am getting **blank listview**.

**Here is my code:**

```
    public class MusicActivity extends Activity {
    ListView musiclist;
    Cursor musiccursor;
    int music_column_index;
    int count;
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          init_phone_music_grid();
    }

    private void init_phone_music_grid() {
          System.gc();
          String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
          musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);

          count = musiccursor.getCount();
          musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneMusicList);
          musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

          musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);
          mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    private OnItemClickListener musicgridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
                System.gc();
                music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);

                try {
                      if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mMediaPlayer.reset();
                      }
                      mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
                      mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                      mMediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
          }
    };


}




    public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public MusicAdapter(Context applicationContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg1;
    }

}
```

Please give me some guideline or idea.

Comment: you need to pass the contents to the adapter that you want to display in listview. In the adapter you need to set the text on your UI component in the `getView()`.Since you are not passing any data to listview and secondly you are handling `getView()`, that is why listview is not populating anything.

Comment: Check this tutorial to get idea about adapter and listview. follow it and edit your Music Adapter code. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html